# AppleID can I transfer data without using the same one?

Tags: iphone, itunes, apple-id, music

I don't want to use the same Apple ID on my new phone as on my old phone because it got messed up, however I don't want to have to buy each app twice. Is there a way I can without using the same Apple ID? Same goes for music.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your old Apple ID to sign in to in the App Store, and use your new ID for everything else on your phone. Just set up the phone using the new ID, then go to “iTunes & App Store” in Settings, log out of the App Store, and log back in using your old ID. Do that before you download any apps.

Comment: A task you will have to repeat each & every time there is an update...